# Kobo e-reader mount cannot write

Tags: macos

I have a **Kobo e-reader** and when I connect it to my MacBook (Intel) it shows up and can see and open the files onto it, but I cannot add .epub files onto it because I have **only read permissions**. The file system is FAT32.
On my Windows computer it works seamlessly.

Running the mount command gives this: `/dev/disk2 on /Volumes/KOBOeReader (msdos, local, nodev, nosuid, read-only, noowners)`

I have have tried manually remounting the tablet:

```
$> mount -uw /Volumes/KOBOeReader 
mount_msdos: /dev/disk2 on /Volumes/KOBOeReader: Operation not permitted
mount: /Volumes/KOBOeReader failed with 71

$> sudo mount -uw /Volumes/KOBOeReader
-
```

Now it shows I have custom permissions, but nothing actually changed.

*Edit: The plot thickens.*
I've just tried to connect it to an older MacBook with a usb connection, and there it works. In my case it's connected to a ***usb-c to usb*** dongle and then to my e-reader so perhaps this is where the issue arises. It's still a bit odd to me, because it does transfer data both ways; so where does the read-only come from?

*Edit 2:* Alas, I don't get the option to ignore ownership.

[image: Mount info]

What do?

Comment: On 13.5 my Kobo (Libra 2 on firmware 4.37.21586) shows up as 'You have custom access' in Finder. On the command line some smoke & mirrors from the mount options is at work and all files are owned by *me*:staff.`mount` returns `/dev/disk4 on /Volumes/KOBOeReader (msdos, local, nodev, nosuid, noowners)` So for me the only difference with OP is not `read-only`. Can you update the question with your macOS version, and Kobo firmware level. Might also be worth seeing if updates are available for either, or if a reboot of both sorts things out.

Comment: I just tried a different macbook with USB-A connection; and there it works. So perhaps the issue arrises from the usb-c to usb dongle. I'll try a different dongle when I'm in the office to check.

Comment: Good idea. I don't have that complication fortunately; both my MBP and Kobo use USB-C, so no dongles.